# C# BackgroundWorker class

Tags: c#, forms, backgroundworker

Currently im trying to update my progress bar if the background worker reports something, heres my code

Form1.cs

```
namespace YTD
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Main app;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n;
            bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(numberBox.Text, out n);

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailBox.Text) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(passBox.Text) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numberBox.Text) && isNumeric)
            {
                this.app = new Main(emailBox.Text, passBox.Text, n, logBox, statusBar, backgroundWorker1);
                this.app.startMule();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all the form fields", "MuleMaker error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my Main.cs

```
namespace YTD.classes
{
    public class Main
    {
        private String email;
        private String password;
        private int number;
        private RichTextBox logBox;
        private ProgressBar statusBar;
        private BackgroundWorker threadWorker;

        public Main(String email, String password, int number, RichTextBox logBox, ProgressBar statusBar, BackgroundWorker threadWorker)
        {
            // Define some variables

            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.number = number;
            this.logBox = logBox;
            this.statusBar = statusBar;
            this.threadWorker = threadWorker;
        }

        public void startMule()
        {
            // Set progressbar 100% value

            statusBar.Maximum = this.number;

            if (!threadWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                threadWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void threadWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                MessageBox.Show("ye");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                threadWorker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
            }
        }

        private void threadWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            statusBar.Increment(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I get no errors but the progress bar value is not beeing changed.
Without the background worker i can update my progress bar fine but not while doing an expensive action.

Comment: You need to do `backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;`

Comment: I did that on the IDE

Comment: is  `threadWorker_DoWork` running?

Comment: I tried several test codes and noone is being executed so looks like not :s

Comment: I was busy and missed it :o)) I was about to telt that in it is not running you have not wired `worker.DoWork` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted Code does not reveal, if you registered your functions to the BackgroundWorker Events.

Creating a new BackgrounWorker isn't enough.
Here is an example:

```
public Class Main
{
    public Main( ... )
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker()
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        // Register to BackgroundWorker-Events
        worker.DoWork += threadWorker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += threadWorker_ProgressChanged;
    }
}
```

in addition you should tell your ProgressBar to rerender.

```
private void threadWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    statusBar.Increment(1);
    statusBar.Invalidate(true);
}
```

at least you might want to use the value you have set calling `ReportProgress(i * 10)`.

```
private void threadWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    statusBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    statusBar.Invalidate(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks BTW one quick question, what sohuld I use this.statusBar or just statusBar?

Comment: I think you could use _this_ or not as you like it. But you should decide if or if not and keep it for the whole project. Since it's mostly clear that you want to use the variable of the local scope I decided to NOT use it.

Comment: Okey and last one, when I run the code everything works. if I click the button again then seems like the background worker is beeing called twice, Im outputing the percentage  of the process. At first it shows correctly : 1, 2, 3 ,4 ... 10 but then if I click again : 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 ... 10, 10

Comment: in your Click-Event: `this.app = new Main( ... )`. So it looks like you always use a NEW! BackgroundWorker and give it to your Main-Method. You should check, if you realy need to instantiate a new Class for each click or you could generate one in your constructor `Form1() { ... }`. If you always use the same object of your Main-Class `startMule()` would do what it's made for: Only start your BackgroundWorker ONCE (per instance of `Main`)!

Comment: Yeah moved some code and now is going good. How do I use variables passed to threadWorker_ProgressChanged ? I mean i must pass something in here this.threadWorker.ReportProgress(i); but how do I access it? I tried e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() but not sure if thats correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55868/discussion-between-myst3rium-and-alvaro-carvajal-nakosmai).